# How to stub a method that passes an enumeration by reference in .net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, rhino-mocks

I am not understanding how this compiles.

I have a VB.net class with the following:

```
Public Class Line
    Public Enum EligibleType
        skipNone = 0
        skipAllow = 1
        skipPay = 2
        skipDeleted = 4
        skipMod = 8
        skipOverride = 16
    End Enum

    Public Function Eligible(Optional ByRef enmEligibleFlag As Line.EligibleType = Line.EligibleType.brSkipNone) As Boolean
End Class
```

This is called over 9,000 times in the application. I tried to write a test method in C# for another function and used Rhino Mocks to create a stub of the class. Then I stubbed the function to always return true. It would not compile.

```
[TestClass]
public class breMATest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Tests the 102.
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test102()
    {
        // Arrange
        br target = new br();
        var line = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Line>();
        line.Stub(s => s.Eligible(ref Arg<Line.EligibleType>.Ref(brBD.Line.EligibleType, Line.EligibleType.skipNone).Dummy).Return(true);

        // Act
        target.Pay102(ref line);

        // Assert
    }
}
```

This gives me:

```
    CS1510: A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable
 UnitTestsCS\brTest.cs(35,13,35,71): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'brBD.Line.Eligible(ref brBD.Line.EligibleType)' has some invalid arguments
```

I tried this as well, with the same results:

```
line.Stub(s => s.Eligible(brBD.Line.EligibleType.skipNone)).Return(true);
```

I tried calling it directly, same error:

```
line.Eligible(ref brBD.Line.EligibleType.skipNone));
```

I understand the error. You can’t pass an enumeration by reference because an enumeration is a constant and can’t be assigned. So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to stub this to always return true?
2. Why does this work in VB.NET?

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Comment: what does `Arg<Line.EligibleType>.Ref(brBD.Line.EligibleType, Line.EligibleType.skipNone)` return? and what is `.Dummy` on that? a property?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I was hoping it would return an object that could be used as a reference. I'd like to use Is.Anything constraint since I am not testing the call to Eligible() but I know the method under test does call it. I could not get that to compile either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are passing as `ref` is:

```
Arg<Line.EligibleType>
  .Ref(brBD.Line.EligibleType, Line.EligibleType.skipNone).Dummy
```

Now; we can't see `Arg<T>.Ref`, but I'm guessing it returns a class upon which `.Dummy` is a property. In C# you *can't pass a property as a `ref`*. I imagine VB elects to spoof this, essentially doing the equivalent of:

```
var tmp = Arg<Line.EligibleType>.Ref(brBD.Line.EligibleType, Line.EligibleType.skipNone).Dummy;
return s.Eligible(ref tmp)
```

However, C# chooses *not* to work this way. IIRC, VB also allows `ref` to be implicit, so there are some very different design aims around how `ref` should be treated.

But I have to agree with C# - in the `ref` usage, you aren't really passing a "reference to the property", so *for me at least*, it avoids incorrect usage to work the way it does - even if that is more explicit.

As an aside: if `.Dummy` was a *field*, then you **can** pass it as `ref`; however, this should not be interpreted as "make `.Dummy` a field"; that is very much *not* what I said ;p

> I understand the error. You can’t pass an enumeration by reference because an enumeration is a constant and can’t be assigned.

You can pass *references to fields*, *references to local variables / parameters*, and *references to things in array* as `ref`; those things can *be* typed as enumerations.

Comment: Related: [The many cases of ByRef](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2010/01/21/the-many-cases-of-byref.aspx)

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan "Copy Back ByRef", "Don’t Copy Back ByRef", "Maybe Copy Back ByRef" oh dear oh dear oh dear; see, this is why I like C#; I can predict what C# is going to *do* ;p

Comment: I really like a lot of VB.Net's features, but the way `ByRef` works is definitely *not* one of them :-)

Comment: I agree. VB must be creating a temp variable behind the scenes for this to work. I created a local type and passed that via .OutRef as James World suggested below. That compiled, however, the VB method is not virtual so I can't stub it. At least not with RhinoMocks. The Line class will need to be changed to implement an interface. *Should* be harmless to do that ;)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Write your stub like this:

```
Line.EligibleType et = Line.EligibleType.SkipNone;
line.Stub(s => s.Eligible(ref et))
    .OutRef(Line.EligibleType.skipNone).Return(true);
```

A ref has to be assignable. You can't pass a constant.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at this and slapped my head because it should have been obvious.